# Is there a way for loading images from local storage to the backgroundImage property of the CircleAvatar widget in Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, widget

I'm having a hard time reading the Flutter doc for the CircleAvatar widget trying to figure out what type is the backgroundImage exactly is.

As far as I know, this property is of ImageProvider type and it can be one of the Asset classes as they extends the ImageProvider.

I came to the conclusion that the only way to get images is via a url or a predefined assets folder.

I want to load images from local storage. I'm currently experimentng this on Android 10.

PLEASE, tell me there is a way to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the ImageProvider you are looking for is `FileImage`. You will only need to pass it the file from local storage. Here are the official docs:

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/FileImage-class.html